# how to link against the libatomic library in gcc

Tags: gcc, dll, linker

I am using header `<atomic>` in my library code and trying to link the program against the `libatomic.so`.

Whenever I try to link all the object files and create my library's SO file, I get error

```
can not find /usr/lib64/libatomic.so.1.0.0
```

I have this so file under path `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5`.
as libatomic.so. No version is specified in the name.

I tried to specify the path `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5` with `-L` option on gcc command creating shared lib, but still it is asking lib `/usr/lib64/libatomic.so.1.0.0` to link against for atomic code.

So how do I against the  `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libatomic.so` in order to create the library?
Why it is asking for libatomic.so.1.0.0 when I do not specify any version in `-latomic` command line option in gcc command.

My gcc version is 4.8.5-4 and OS is redhat 7.2

Answer (score 2):

Look at the *content* of the file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libatomic.so! You'll probably see it is not an actual library, but just a single line of text which looks like:

```
INPUT ( /usr/lib64/libatomic.so.1.0.0 )
```

So when you use "-latomic", this file is picked up (as you wanted!) and then the linker goes on to find /usr/lib64/libatomic.so.1.0.0 - which is missing. To have it, you should probably install the "libatomic" package (`yum install libatomic`). You can also use "yum whatprovides /usr/lib64/libatomic.so.1.0.0" to automatically find the package which should have provided this file.